# How can I separate consecutive strings without any delimiters?

Tags: vcf-variant-call-format

My input data is a VCF (Variant Call Format) file. Each line that I am interested in looks like this:

```
chrI    22232   DEL00BED        N       <DEL>   .       PASS   SUPP=1159;SUPP_VEC=11111111111111111111111011111111111
```

I want to count the presence (1) of a specific deletion in a specific position (22232) supported by n samples. For this reason, I looked at `SUPP_VEC=` values, however, I don't know how to split each value as 1) it is a string, and 2) doesn't have delimiters. How could I add a space between every character? or How could I split/ count the values from `SUPP_VEC=` for Python3?

I was also curious to know what `SUPP` means. I found one`SUPP=2`and I looked on Excel if the presence(1)\abscence(0) in the `SUPP_VEC` counted the value of `SUPP`, nevertheless, I could only count 1 instead of 2, probably does somebody know what `SUPP` means.

The reason for my procedure is to have a frequency table for a specific deletion type.

I hope I made myself clear.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think whitspace is the delimiter. By the way you didn't put any information about which language you use.

Comment: I already found the answer. Something simple: a for loop, and SUPP counts already the total presence of a deletion in N samples.  I mentioned Python 3,, sorry if that was not completely understood.

Comment: Ok my dyslexia strikes again but in order to the platform (stackoverflow) to handle correctly this information, you need to tag your question (users are filtering by tags).